# Linux setup not recognizing AMD RX580GTS GPU

Tags: linux

I've recently switched to Linux Mint 20.  GPU drivers are installed (included in the kernel) but blender and blender alone will not see the GPU.  Blender runs fine OTHER than not recognizing my GPU.  I've followed guides which had me install proprietary drivers from AMD but still blender sees nothing.  Can anyone point me at some information?

Linux Mint 20
Blender 2.83
Radeon RX580GTS
Ryzen 3600X

Comment: Did you dowload Blender from Blender.org? if not, try that

Comment: I tried both loading 8.3 thru the included program manager (I can't think of the name right now as I'm not in linux) and I tried grabbing the latest 2.83 build from blender.org

Comment: I also just backed up and tried 2.81 and 2.82 as well as 2.90b with no luck.  Same thing in every case.